# Posix: How do I initialize a mutex in locked state?

Tags: unix, synchronization, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

When working with semaphores, often, in order to enforce synchronization among threads, I find useful to initialize a semaphore to zero.

In this way I can have some part of the code executed only after another thread has signaled on that semaphore.

Can this be achieved with mutexes, too?

I explain better: when I initialize a Posix Mutex ( e.g. via `pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL)` ) it is normally initialized in an unlocked state, so that the first thread trying to lock it would be successful.

I was wondering if there's a way to initialized a mutex in a locked state (the equivalent of using `sem_init(&sem,0,0)` with a semaphore), maybe by using some attributes for mutex or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there seems no way to initialize a mutex of locked state. According to [opengroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html):

> The pthread_mutex_init() function shall initialize the mutex referenced by mutex with attributes specified by attr. If attr is NULL, the default mutex attributes are used; the effect shall be the same as passing the address of a default mutex attributes object. **Upon successful initialization, the state of the mutex becomes initialized and unlocked.**

Thus we have to lock it manually. A wrapper function may make things less ugly :-)